# Execute SQL Query multiple times in Excel and change variable based off row

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, excel-formula

Basically I have an *Excel* sheet, with a list of about 5k+ social security numbers, and I want to add their email addresses to the *Excel* table.

Is it possible to set up the spreadsheet to run a simple sql query like:

```
SELECT emailaddress
FROM table
WHERE ssn = '?'
```

Except have it automatically change the variable depending on what row the query is on, as well as have it automatically run down the spreadsheet just querying with the respective ssn?

Thanks!

----------------------------------------EDIT-------------------------------------------------

I guess if it helps to clarify, here is a basic example of what my excel sheet looks like:

```
        A          B             C             D            E
 1  |  Name |   Address   | Phone Number |  Social     |          |
 2  | Brian | 123 Abc ST. | 555-1234     | 111-22-3333 |          |
 3  | John  | 88 N. Road  | 444-4848     | 123-45-4568 |          |

Etc...
```

Our database has this, plus more fields, so I want to include their email, and add it to the table.

```
        A          B             C             D                 E
 1  |  Name |   Address   | Phone Number |  Social     |       Email      |
 2  | Brian | 123 Abc ST. | 555-1234     | 111-22-3333 | brian@gmail.com  |
 3  | John  | 88 N. Road  | 444-4848     | 123-45-4568 | john@hotmail.com |

                                                         ^Add this column^
```

And basically just put the same query in the email column, and have it reference it's respective SSN cell. So the same query would go into both Brian and John's email cell, but the variable would automaticall choose the social in the same row.

```
Query:
SELECT emailaddress
FROM table             <-------------Use this query in this column--|
WHERE ssn = '?'                      But have the variable change   |
                                     depending on the row it is in  V

        A          B             C             D                 E
 1  |  Name |   Address   | Phone Number |  Social     |         Email        |
 2  | Brian | 123 Abc ST. | 555-1234     | 111-22-3333 | "...where ssn = (D2)"|
 3  | John  | 88 N. Road  | 444-4848     | 123-45-4568 | "...where ssn = (D3)"|

                                                            ^Query Example^
```

Hope that clarifies things.

Comment: Are you doing this to add the email addresses to the spreadsheet or are the email addresses already there?  I am not entirely clear on your objective. It is possible to query an Excel table with SQL like you would a relational database.

Comment: You would be better off doing a data dump to a temporary worksheet (or just memory) thereby localizing the data and repeating your inquiries to that.

Comment: Can you describe what your Excel source table looks like?  I'm thinking you might be able to accomplish this with a `VLOOKUP()` or something similar, but you haven't given us enough information.

Comment: @Soulfire, I am going to be adding the email address to the excel table.

Comment: @Jeeped, do you by chance any links/references that could show me some examples of what exactly you talking about? Thanks!

Comment: @Marc The excel sheet is just table with about 5,000 entries. Each column is just stuff like Name, Address, SSN, Phone Number, etc. Did that answer your question? Also what other information do you think I should include in the question? Thanks!

Comment: Why not just query the DB for what you want to export that to Excel?  Wouldn't that solve your problem?

Comment: @Marc, I also edited the question and tried to provide a more clear example of what I'm asking. Thanks!

Comment: @Marc, I would, but I have a dataset of 5000 ssns.

Comment: How many records are in the table you want to query?  Basically, I'm thinking dump the source table to Excel and `VLOOKUP()` against that.  But if you have millions of records in the source table, that's impractical.

Comment: @Marc, yeah our DB is huge....that wouldn't work :(

Comment: Well then, just construct multiple queries with a `select [your_desired_fields] from table where SSN in (ssn-1, ssn-2, ... ssn-N)` for as many comma delimited parameters as your DB's `IN` clause will accept (e.g., Oracle caps it at 1,000 I think).  And piece them together manually or with a `UNION` of the queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best you can do is construct multiple queries against your read-only database with something like:

```
select [your_desired_fields]
  from table
 where SSN in (ssn-1, ssn-2, ... ssn-N);
```

for as many comma delimited parameters as your MySQL's `IN` clause will accept (e.g., Oracle caps it at 1,000). Then piece the results together manually or with a UNION of the queries.

I use Oracle, but I think if you wanted to union them, you could do:

```
select [your_desired_fields]
  from table
 where SSN in (ssn-1, ssn-2, ... ssn-1000)
UNION
select [your_desired_fields]
  from table
 where SSN in (ssn-1001, ssn-2, ... ssn-2000)
UNION
   etc, etc.
```

The `Range2Csv()` VBA function here could help to construct that query:
http://dullsharpness.com/2011/11/14/excel-vba-range-to-csv-range2csv-function/

Comment: Ah, that's what I was afraid of. Oh well, I appreciate your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to load your SSNs all to SQL, then pull them back into Excel with the `emailaddress` field added.

Create a table to store the data in the database:

```
CREATE TABLE ssn (ssn CHAR(9));
```

Now in Excel, use this formula to generate INSERT statements to load the SSNs. This assumes the data is in column A, and starts on row two.  The tricky part here is making sure to get the double and single quotes in properly!

```
=CONCATENATE("INSERT ssn VALUES ('",A2,"');")
```

Fill that formula down to the bottom of your data, then copy/paste over to SQL.  You can now join all the SSNs to the table including email addresses like so:

```
SELECT s.ssn, t.emailaddress
    FROM ssn s
    INNER JOIN table t ON s.ssn = t.ssn
```

I have a more detailed example of this towards the bottom of this post on my blog under "Quick Contact statement", https://www.rustprooflabs.com/2015/08/sql-for-ir

Comment: Thank you for the help, however unfortunately I only have read only privileges to the DB.

Comment: Ah, I was afraid of that.  I don't have time to write up the details of using VBA specific to MySQL, but I wrote a post a while back covering the basics of this using SQL Server.  I think you should be able to update the `connString` variable for your DB, and the rest should be valid:    https://www.rustprooflabs.com/2015/04/excel-vba-sql-reporting -- Skip down to the heading "Manual Processes Suck".